# Spring Security "Refused to execute script from ..."

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm building a Spring MVC application with Spring Security and Bootstrap in my HTML files (thymeleaf templates). The Spring Security part is based on the Spring Guide [for Spring Security](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) and combined with a Spring Boot application server.

After enabling Spring Security the bootstrap css file won't load with the error message:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/js/bootstrap.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

The error message above comes from the chrome developer console.

***What I've tried:***

- Disabling the Spring Security
  => bootstrap css works again, but I need the security
- Searching on the spring forums, but theres a looped link without a solution
- Adding a resources handler, but I can't see that the handler is invoked nor the error disappears
- Adding the resources path to the `permit` call

My dir structure:

```
/main
  |-> /java
       | BootStart.java
       |-> /security
              |SecurityConfiguration.java
  |-> /resources
         |-> /static
               |-> /css /** bootstrap location */
               |-> /js
               |-> /fonts
         |-> /templates
               | /user
                   | sample.html
```

BootStart.java is the java file that gets picked up by Spring Boot.

BootStart.java:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class BootStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BootStart.class, args);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/resources/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Sample.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-theme.css}" href="../../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">!Basic template!</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently I'm using the following dependencies in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

How must I configure Spring Security that I can load css/ js files from my /static resources directory?

Answer (score 21):

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920752/966698) by other with similar question.

If you place js files in `/js/` dir, there should not that kind of MIME error.
And, for javascript files, it is better to disable security for them:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/the_js_path/**");
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I had the same error too with the same folder structure, it was on the css file.

All I did is added `/css/**` in antMatcher() as below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll() //Adding this line solved it
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/sign-in")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .failureUrl("/error")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable();

}
```

In your case just add `/js/**` in the antMatcher() and then use permitAll()

Answer (score 3):

I used this to resolved my problem, you may try this

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and struggled for a while. I had created a route which should match every "unmatched" route, and send `index.html`.

```
@Controller
public class DefaultPageController {
  @Autowired
  private LogService logService;

  @GetMapping("/*")
  public String defaultPage(Model model){
      logService.saveLog(Log.LogType.INFO, null, "Default route");
      return "index";
  }
}
```

The problem was, that it overrode the route `/file.js`, and didn't send the static files, but always `index.html`.

So the solution was only to customize the route.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after adding a new method to a controller.

I forgot to provide a value for the `@GetMapping` annotation and the `@Controller` itself was not bound to any URL. Wierdly enough adding `@GetMapping("/foo")` to my method solved the problem. I still haven't figured out why that happened but I'm planning to find out.

Answer (score 0):

when we use "**permitall()**" or **anyrequest()** then it enable Mime check so i specify all url listing which use to be accecs.

Answer (score 0):

I removed any comments from the beginning of the css file and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Checklists to import static resources file into Spring MVC with Security Web Configuration:

1. Permit pattern matcher in configure method which extends from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
    @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage").loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateUser")
                .permitAll();
        }
```

2. Mapping resources location in configuration by implements WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```

3. Create the resources folder and subfolders to store the static files.

```
/src/main/webapp/
    |-> resources
      | -> css
        | -> style.css
```

4. Add resources into the JSP file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

5. Remember that in the controller file always specify the path even though the home page
   `@RequestMapping("/")`